# Image doesn't show in email

Tags: excel, vba, image, email, outlook

I am trying to send bulk email via Outlook with two attachments (one logo and one picture of a signature).

When I `.send` the images don't show in the received email.
They do show, if I first use `.display` then send manually.

```
Sub GenerateEMail()

'set abbreviations for workbook and sheets
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim wsInput As Worksheet: Set wsInput = wb.Sheets("Input")
Dim wsTool As Worksheet: Set wsTool = wb.Sheets("Tool")
Dim outObj As Object
Dim Mail As Object
Set outObj = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Dim olkPA As Outlook.PropertyAccessor
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"

'Fasten Macro
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'get information from sheet "Tool"
'E-Mail
Subject = wsTool.Range("Subjet").Value
Text = wsTool.Range("Text").Value

'Signatures
Signature = wsTool.Range("Sig").Value & "\" & wsTool.Range("NameSig").Value

'Logo
Logo = wsTool.Range("Logo").Value & "\" & wsTool.Range("NameLogo").Value

'get relevant columns from sheet "Input"
ColEMail = Split(Cells(1, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsTool.Range("ColNameMail"), wsInput.Range("1:1"), 0)).Address, "$")(1)

'generate E-Mail for each line (range defined in wsTool)

firstRow = wsTool.Range("From").Value
If wsTool.Range("To").Value <> "" And wsTool.Range("To").Value <> " " Then
    lastRow = wsTool.Range("To").Value
Else
    lastRow = wsInput.Cells(wsInput.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End If

For Line = firstRow To lastRow
    
    'opens additional E-Mail
    Set Mail = outObj.createitem(0)
    Set olkPA = Mail.PropertyAccessor

    olkPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "Signature.png"
    olkPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "Logo.png"




        .Subject = Subject

        '.
        'Body with Foto of Signatures & Logo
        .HTMLBody = "<img src='" & Logo & "'>" & "<br><br>" & _
               
         Text & "<br>" & _
    
         "<img src='" & Signature & "'>" 

        .To = wsInput.Range(ColEMail & Line).Value

    End With

    Mail.send
    
Next Line

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the message itself - you must add the attachment (`MailItem.Attachments.Add`) and then set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property on the returned `Attachment` object to the value matching the cid attribute on the img tag.